# How to customize a ListView row to get a glass background?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get a glass like background for each row of my ListView. But using the following codes I am getting a glass like background for the whole Listview. I just Want glass like background for each row. I am posting my xml code below. Please suggest how can I get the glass like background for only the rows and not the whole of the ListView.

Xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".Lists"
   android:background="@drawable/backgnd" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:background="#20535252"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Used `Custom Adapter` and set `Background` To your `Custom Adapter Layout`

Comment: have you used getView method in adapter?

Comment: I am using SimpleAdapter. Is it possible using SimpleAdapter?

Comment: I have not used getView method

Comment: If you want to after select row background change then you can set **listSelector** for listView.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA i doubt setting listSelector will do that !!

Comment: I just want the row to be displayed with a glass background. I mean when I go to that activity the row should be in a glass background. can you suggest sumthing?

Comment: you can use custom adapter for that. @r4jiv007 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".Lists"
   android:background="@drawable/backgnd" >


<!-- your custom views -->
 </RelativeLayout>
```

now use this layout to inflate your listview's item.
you can use a custom adapter something like this :-

```
  public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



        public int getCount() {
            return ItemList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return ItemList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

//inflate your layout here :-
            if(view ==null)
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null); 


            return view;

        }

    }
```